# Nhibernate Save() not working

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I have googled around everything for this problem and I am not sure what the problem is with my code. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out. I am working with adding custom data to uCommerce 7.2.2, means extending the order details by adding a new tab.

For this I have created a new table like this -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[uCommerce_OrderLineItemStatusAudit](
       [OrderLineItemStatusAuditId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [LineOrderStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
       [RefOrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
       [Sku] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
       [OrderLineItemStatusAuditId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The entity -

```
public class OrderLineItemStatusAudit : IEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int OrderLineItemStatusAuditId { get; set; }
        public virtual int LineOrderStatusId { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual int RefOrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Message { get; set; }
        public virtual string Sku { get; set; }

    }
```

Mappings done for the table and the entity -

```
public class OrderLineItemStatusAuditMap : BaseClassMap<OrderLineItemStatusAudit>
    {
        public OrderLineItemStatusAuditMap()
        {
            Table("uCommerce_OrderLineItemStatusAudit");
            Id(x => x.OrderLineItemStatusAuditId, "OrderLineItemStatusAuditId");
            Map(x => x.LineOrderStatusId).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Sku).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.CreatedOn).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.CreatedBy).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.RefOrderId).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Message).Nullable();
        }
    }
```

And this is the save method where I am getting the exception -

```
private void Save(OrderLine orderLine)
        {
            orderLine.Save();

            var orderLineStatus = new OrderLineItemStatusAudit
                {                
                    LineOrderStatusId = 2,
                    Sku = orderLine.Sku,
                    CreatedOn = orderLine.CreatedOn,
                    CreatedBy = "test",
                    RefOrderId = orderLine.OrderLineId,
                    Message = null
                };            
            _orderLineItemStatus.Save(orderLineStatus); // **getting exception here - Cannot insert null to LineOrderStatusId  column**

        }
```

I have referred this doc - [Save custom data](http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.6/extending-ucommerce/save-custom-data-in-the-database.html)

Create Mapping Assembly Tag and Registering the assembly tag is also done.

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: save or update? where do you ISession.Commit / Flush? http://www.karlgjertsen.com/nhibernate-flush-vs-commit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem and I think I should post it here too.

NHibernate treats property names by convention and that "LineOrderStatusId" would be treated like a foreign key. In this case it is good to use a Reference in the mappings for that class instead and have NHibernate take care of the relation.

If the column name has an Id postfixed then it would be treated as a reference to some parent table. This is the convention being used by uCommerce nHibernate mappings.

Thanks